# Python yield does not return value in class method

Tags: python, class, generator

I tried to get the values of a generator in the form of a list inside a method of a class as the following example:

```py
class Series:
    def __init__(self, x, raw_data, window):
        self.x = x
        self.raw_data = raw_data
        self.data = self.extract(window)
    
    def extract (self, window):
       #Some calculation
       yield result

    def get_val(self):
        for point in self.data:
            yield point.val
        
    def plot(self):
        y = list(self.get_val())
        plt.plot(self.x, y)
```

For some reason the value of `y` in the `plot` method is `[]`. I tried calling `get_val` outside of the method and it worked just fine. Why is the generator not returning anything at the method?

Comment: Can you also show me how are you creating the class instance and calling the methods?

Comment: Can you explain why you are using generators?  Why not return self.data directly?

Comment: I can't confirm this with a simplified code. Could you add some more code to make a reproducible example? A **minimal** reproducible example. Drop `x`, `raw_data`, `window` and the `extract` method and set some fixed values for `self.data`.

Comment: Wild guess: `self.data` is not a list, but a generator and in your real code you call `get_val` twice. When you call it a second time the generator is exhausted and doesn't produce any more values. Can you check the type of `self.data`?